# Chrome no sound in the server but in the client does

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, intranet

I have an index.html file that have this:

My server is Windows server 2016 ver 1607(OS Build 14393.2035), 
IIS version 10.0.14393.0, 
Firewall off,
Running the browsers on client window 7 and 8.
With Internet explorer 11.0.9600.18698 works all follow scenarios,
 but with Google chrome 67.0.3396.62 nop :(

running Chrome http://servername/index.html , no sounds.

If I copy same file to the desktop same chrome works! file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/sound.html

If I map the server to “Y” and run the file file:///Y:/inetpub/wwwroot/index.html  Chrome  works. :)

I need to run a Chrome browser in the intranet client and need the server html  sounds.
Who can I do?

Comment: This is the file:            <embed height='0' width='0' src='\\servername\mysound.wav'/>

Comment: Does the console of chrome return an error?

Comment: Yes, Not allowed to load local resource: but  OK, you are Rigth, if I copy that file to the root directory it works,  Curious think was it works with explorer but chrome wasn't.  Anyway you help me! Thank you, very glad!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the src is not actually requesting from the server.

Try

```
<embed height='0' width='0' src='//servername/mysound.wav'/>
```

Comment: Now Explorer is not working, but anyway I need Chrome.  Thanks

Comment: @dipsiecamilla great, thanks! please mark the answer as accepted :) (I'm trying to be able to comment everywhere and need the rep)

Comment: for internet explorer...maybe you need to actually type the http://servername/mysound.wav as it might handle protocol relative urls differently. otherwise it's probably an incompatibility with the embed tag...I'd check the console for that browser as well

Comment: relytmcd, Your answer is correct, but I have no enough points.

Comment: @dipsiecamila as the asker you have a special privilege to mark an answer as accepted https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers